# Stuck defining large 2d-array - c++

Tags: c++, arrays, image, primes

For fun I'm writing a program that creates an image using primes. For this I create an 2d-array of all the natural numbers up to a certain point. 
 
Primes are represented in the image as a black pixel, and composite numbers are white.
The program works for dimensions less than 1000*1000, but when it exceeds that it gets stuck.
How do I fix it, any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(long long a){

  if(a==1){return false;}

  if(a==2){return true;}

  if(a%2==0){return false;}

  long long root = sqrt(a);
  for(long long i=3;i<=root;i+=2){
    if(a%i==0){return false;}
  }
  return true;
}

int main(){
  int width = 0, height = 0;
  cout << "Which dimentions do you want the picture to be?" << endl;
  cout << "Width: " << flush;
  cin >> width;
  cout << "Height: " << flush;
  cin >> height;

  /*Create matrix*/
  long long imageMap[height][width];
  long long numberOfPixels = width*height;
  long long i = 1;
  long long x = 0 , y = 0;
  cout << "Number of pixels the image will have: " << numberOfPixels << endl;

  while(i<=numberOfPixels){
    imageMap[x][y] = i;
    x++;
    if(x==width){
      y++;
      x=0;
    }
    i++;
  }

  cout << "Image map done" << endl;
  cout << "Creating prime map, please wait..." << endl;


  /*Generate prime map*/
  int primeMap[width][height]; //The program gets stuck here


  for(long long y = 0; y < width; y++){
    for(long long x = 0; x < height; x++){
      if(isPrime(imageMap[x][y])){
        primeMap[y][x] = 1;
      } else {
        primeMap[y][x] = 0;
      }
      cout << " x = " << x << flush;
    }
    cout << endl << "y = " << y << endl;
  }

  cout << "Writing to file, please wait..." << endl;

  /*Write to file*/
  ofstream primeImage;
  primeImage.open("prime.pbm");

  primeImage << "P1 \n";
  primeImage << width << " " << height << "\n";

  for(int y = 0; y < width; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < height; x++){
      primeImage << primeMap[y][x] << " ";
    }
    primeImage << "\n";
  }
  primeImage.close();
  cout << "Map creation done" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it gets stuck" What does that mean? Please be specific

Comment: Two problems: First of all C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), secondly stack size (where local variable, including arrays) are stored by the compilers is very limited. The default stack-side on Windows is 1MB per process. You are attempting to create an 8MB array on the stack.

Comment: As for a possible solution, I suggest you learn about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Btw, unrelated, note the values you're storing in `primeMap`. Do you *really* need a `long long` to hold only the values `0` or `1`?  Yeah. not really; `unsigned char`. That just saved you a likely 7/8ths the footprint of your current map right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default size stack for an app is 1MB, if memory serves. Joachim is correct, the best way forward is to learn about std::vector. But if this is just a fun throwaway program, you could simply increase the stack size to get it working. If you're using visual studio, open the project properties and look at the linker system tab. You can can use the stack reserve value to increase the stack size. But I wouldn't recommend doing this for an actual work project.

BTW: If joachim wants to repost his comment as an answer, I suggest you accept that one.